# Trying to make a list item strikethrough onClick, but instead it's breaking my submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm making a tasklist program using react and redux and I wrote a function to remove items from the list when you click on them and add them to a second list, but struck through. I'm trying to make the function trigger onClick on each list item, but for some reason when I add the event to it, when I click on the submit button to add a new task everything on the page disappears.

I've already tried other events like onMouseDown, and they all caused the same thing. I tried changing various parts of the code but the only thing that seems to break it is adding the onClick event.

The function for handling the list removal is here

```
const taskReducer = (state = [[],[]], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD: 
            return [state[0].concat(action.task), [...state[1]]];
        case COMP:
            let idx = indexOf(state[0].filter(action.task));
            let beg = state.slice(0, idx);
            let end = state.slice(idx + 1);
            let newState = [[...beg, ...end], [...state[1], action.task]];
            return newState;
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the part that generates the button and two lists is here

```
<button 
   id = 'submitGoal'
   onClick = {this.submitHandler} >Submit</button>
<ul id = 'currentTasks'>
   {this.props.tasks.map( (task, idx) => {
        return (
             <li onClick = {this.completeHandler(event.target)} key={idx}>{task}</li>
             )
        })
   }
</ul>
<ul id = 'completedTasks'>
     {this.props.compTasks.map( (task, idx) => {
          return (
               <li key={idx}>{task}</li>
               )
          })
     }
</ul>
```

The whole program is also live right now at https://jeengland.github.io/molehills/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you looked in your console? What does the error says there(if there any)?

Comment: OK, I got `indexOf is not defined` in console, and my guess is that you probably wanted to call `indexOf` on the whole array of tasks, like `allTasks.indexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `indexOf` not being defined in your `taskReducer`. I took a look at your example and inspected the console to get this:

[image]

[image]

I think you mean to use Array.indexOf here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Ah I completely forgot to check the console where I was running it. This is the first webapp I'm building on my own and I'm learning on my own so I completely glossed over that as an option. Thank you so much for your help!